# How do I change incoming packet from NIC in C?

Tags: c, network-programming

libpcap can only **read** the packets, how can I **change** it?

Basically I want to register a callback function that operates on all incoming packets,

how can this be done?

Comment: Please specify an operating system, stuff like this is typically very non-portable.

Comment: If you want every packet destined for one particular process to be transformed (but leave other processes unaffected), you have one set of modifications to make - possibly in the program itself.  If you want every packet for every program ever to go through your code, you have to put your code into the TCP/IP stack, which is usually inside the kernel.  That is a much harder thing to do (and a good thing too - having the communications tampered with by the system smacks of a police state).

Comment: On the linux kernel, you can modify the syscalls.

Comment: Write/modify the IP driver. I suggest reading the IP protocol RFC. Further, you probably want to spent some serious time studying, this task is not easy.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of traffic is this? How do you want to modify it? What OS?

On linux, you may be able to use iptables to have the kernel modify the packets for you.

If that can't do what you want (i.e., you need to get the packets into user space), you could look at [netfilter_queue](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/index.html). Or as a simpler alternative, use an iptables REDIRECT rule to send all the packets to a single port, and write an application to listen on that port.